# How find this sum of in analytic numbers theory?

Tags: analytic-number-theory

find the summion

> $$\sum_{p\le x}\dfrac{1}{(p-1)^2}\sum_{m=1}^{p-1}\sum_{\chi{(p)}}\sum_{a=1}^{p-1}\chi^m{(a)}e\left(\dfrac{a}{p}\right)$$

this problem is  my friend gave me a question, he claimed that few people will be this, but I don't believe, I thought for a long time, but there is no solution, so I could please help me calculate, thank you very much.

and I know this topic is the problem in analytic number theory,But I can't,Thank you